# add timezone for a given time in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

i need to convert the given Australian times to UTC. this time can be from different states in AUS.  i have the states in the DB and stored the time offset in a column.

i want to know how is possible to add a time offset or subtract it this way.

// stored values of states and its column.

```
"NT" = +9.30
"QLD" = +10.00
"WA" = +8.00
```

i am taking selected date time this way and need to reduce the offset.

```
$timeAinUTC = date("H:i A", strtotime("07am")) - (offset); 

i.e $timeAinUTC = date("H:i A", strtotime("07am")) - (+9.30);
```

how can i get this kind of a work done with php's datetime ?

**EDIT 1,**

I tried this to add my offeset but it seems like i cannot provide double values like 2.30 hours or 2.50

It works when i ask it to add 2 hours this way.

```
strtotime($current_time . "+2hours");
```

but when i add like below , its wrong.

```
strtotime($current_time . "+2.30hours");
```

**EDIT 2**

All the sates available in AUS. 
ACT, NSW, NT, QLD, SA, TAS, VIC, WA

http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/australia/time-zones/

**EDIT 3**

I tried this as below as explained by a person in the answer.

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-10-01 01:45', new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A') . "<br>";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A') . "<br>";
```

But it outputs,

```
2013-10-01 01:45:00 AM
2013-09-30 03:45:00 PM
```

How can this be wrong ? 2013-09-30 03:45:00 PM is wrong as per my understaing and actually it should be 10 hours behind from 2013-10-01 01:45:00 AM to be UTC, isnt it ?

Comment: One issue you might have is that some times change. For example in the UK we have daylight savings time, therefore you would have to figure out when all the time changes are and run a script  to the DB to change the offsets. Better to do store the timezone and time and then change calculate difference when you need to in PHP.

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom you mean in this format the zone only ? 'Australia/Queensland' if so, i am wondering will it automatically handle the daylight saving and all ?

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom can you please check the edited section 2. i couldn't make it work with your answer.  what am i missing ?

Comment: I think that is correct http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20131001T0145&p1=152&p2=0

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom Oppz, its my mistake. tnx a lot :)

Comment: About **edit3**, it is 10 hours behind. `01:45AM - 10hours = 03:45PM`. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Glavić there is no problem. its resolved and i have misunderstood.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert times like this:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2013-10-01', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

PHP Supported timezones are listed here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php

Comment: +1 Much better to let PHP worry about what offset each timezone is.

Comment: @Mark is PHP has timing for all these zones in AUS ? http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/australia/time-zones/ i mean all states. ACT, NSW, NT, QLD, SA, TAS, VIC, WA

Comment: I have edited the answer with a list of supported time zones.

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom ok tnx. will this handle the daylight saving automatically ?

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom can you please check the edited section 2. i couldn't make it work with your answer.  what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope, below solution of changing timezone at run time will help you.

```
$date = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "<br>";

$date = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "<br>";

$date = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/Salta'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "<br>";
```

Output when i checked:

```
2020-03-18 20:54:08+05:30
2020-03-18 15:24:08+00:00
2020-03-18 12:24:08-03:00
```

You can also set your own date instead of "date('Y-m-d H:i:s')".

Thanks for asking this question.